# Null Safety in Dart

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, dart-null-safety

Recently dart realeased the new feature called null safety. I have a little bit confusion in how to create constructors with named parameters. When I follow the use of curly braces, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
void main() {
  
}

class Student {
  String name = '';
  num age = 0;
  List<num> marks = [];
  
  Student({
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.marks
    });
  
  void printStudentDetails() {
    print('Student Name: ' + this.name);
  }
}
```

And here is the error that I get:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the properties of your class are not nullable (type is `String` instead of `String?` for example), you either need to add `required` to the properties  in the constructor, or provide a default value (which seems to be what you want to do).

```dart
  Student({
    this.name = '',
    this.age = 0,
    this.marks = [],
    });
```

You can now probably also make your properties final:

```
final String name;
final num age;
final List<num> marks;
```

Or, with the required keyword:

```
  Student({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.marks,
    });
```